# What is the electrostatic force between charges if they separated by a combination of dielectric media?

Tags: electrostatics

How does the combination of different medium affect the force? How do we calculate the equivalent dielectric constant?
Say, two charges are separated by 100 cm, first 10 cm is a slab of dielectric constant 100, the last 10 cm is another slab of constant 50, rest is air.